# It looks like reducers are not working correctly when using createSlice

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm using the https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/quick-start documentation to create a global state in a typescript React app.

In the reducer of the SetEditToPreviewState function, the object's Proxy must be passed in the state parameter, which allows you to change the object's properties without using the immutable state.

But when I change the properties of the state property, the tree is not redrawn.
The debugger shows that the class itself is passed to my reducers function, and not its Proxy wrapper.

Do not prompt why it can be?

The stack shows that for some reason Immer functions are not used at all in this call.

Here is screen and part of code

[image]

file1.ts

```js
export enum EditFormState {
  Edit,
  PreviewToPost,
  ShowResult,
  NewOrder
};

export class MyFormValues {
  private _softLicenTypeID: string = '';

  public set SoftLicenTypeID(value: string) {
    if (this._softLicenTypeID !== value) {
      this._softLicenTypeID = value;
      this.OnSoftLicenTypeIDChanged();
    }
  }

  public get SoftLicenTypeID(): string {
    return this._softLicenTypeID;
  }

  private OnSoftLicenTypeIDChanged() {}

  SoftLicenceTypeName: string = '';
  SoftLicenceTypeDescription: string = '';
  SoftLicencePriceComment: string = '';
}

export class GlobalStateType {
  public State: EditFormState = EditFormState.Edit;
  public FormData: MyFormValues = new MyFormValues();
}

const initialState: GlobalStateType = new GlobalStateType();

const mainStateSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'mainStateSlice',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    //SetEditToPreviewState: (state: WritableDraft<GlobalStateType>, action: PayloadAction<MyFormValues>): void => {
    SetEditToPreviewState: (state, action: PayloadAction < MyFormValues > ) => {
      state.State = EditFormState.PreviewToPost;
      Object.assign(state.FormData, action.payload);
    },

    SetShowSentResultState: (state: WritableDraft < GlobalStateType > ): void => {
      state.State = EditFormState.ShowResult;
    },

    SetEditState: (state: WritableDraft < GlobalStateType > ): void => {
      state.State = EditFormState.Edit;
    },

    SetNewOrderState: (state: WritableDraft < GlobalStateType > ): void => {
      state.State = EditFormState.NewOrder;
      Object.assign(state.FormData, initialState);
    },
  },
});

export const mainStateSliceActions = mainStateSlice.actions;
```

file2.ts

```js
function onSubmit(values: MyFormValues, actions: any) {
  //Object.assign(props.FormData, values);
  //actions.setSubmitting(false);
  //props.SetNextState(EditFormState.PreviewToPost);

  dispatch(mainStateSliceActions.SetEditToPreviewState(formData));
}
```

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "eh-lib-dir-pay-react-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/dateformat": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.11",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.27",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.10",
    "@types/validator": "^13.7.13",
    "axios": "^1.3.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "dateformat": "^5.0.3",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4",
    "validator": "^13.9.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "sass": "^1.62.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: you will likely get more answers if you install the demo in `https://codesandbox.io` such that developers can see the issue with one click

Answer (score 1):

Classes are generally not immerized, since they can often not safely be cloned. Generally, you should never store any kind of classes in Redux state, since they are non-serializable and will cause all kinds of problems if you ever want to use redux-persist or other utilities from the ecosystem. Redux is meant to hold data, not code.

Comment: If redux doesn't support classes as a state store, why doesn't the library throw normal errors when compiling or running, to make it clear?

Comment: In dev, you should be seeing tons of warnings about non-serializable values in store, assuming you didn't disable the middleware for that manually.